How did "dream" become a verb without the same thing happening to "nightmare"?
You can say I had a dream and you can say I had a nightmare. But then you can say He is dreaming, yet you cannot say He is nightmaring....you have to say He is having a nightmare.
Why is that? How did the one shift without the same thing happening to the other? When did this shift occur? Or was dream always a verb? Was there a ever a verb for nightmaring?

I know Gen-Z happily makes up verbs via gerund as they see fit. If there is noun Q you can describe as a state of being then Q-ing exists. Example “adulting”. In casual speak for example recounting a story of bad psychedelic trip you could say “I was just nightmaring” and that would probably fly okay. But it’s very very niche.

True, but unrelated, since I'm interested here in the traditional centuries-old  uses of the words rather than just what kids having been saying since the 2010s, which doesn't really have any bearing on historical usage.

@SidharthGhoshal Certainly their learnings and trainings are grating enough and then some, but more scandalous by far is their habit of using the base form of a verb as though it were a noun: an ask, a spend, a think, a rethink, an overtake, an amaze, a hurl, a prove, a transmit, a retransmit, a soar, a follow. :)

Apparently it was originally a verb:                              The earliest known use of the verb nightmare is in the mid 1600s.
OED's earliest evidence for nightmare is from 1660, in the writing of Robert Wild, nonconformist minister and satirical poet.
It is also recorded as a noun from the Middle English period (1150—1500). https://www.oed.com/dictionary/nightmare_v?tl=true

Why is "to murder" much commoner than "to manslaughter", or "to feel" than "to propriocept"? I would guess dreams are more common than nightmares, "dream" is shorter and more convenient to use, "dream" has a lot of metaphorical extensions compared to nightmare (although that may in part be due to the first two things), and English has many other words for imagining bad things that can be used instead. But you won't find a single reason why, or clear proof of it.

A good answer would look at the history of the two words (confirmation of 'what', and then (much more work) look at similar pairs (if they exist). That will go some way to doing more than just speculation on one instance.

Chaucer would be a source.

It isn't really possible to answer "why" questions like this. It's all just accidents of history. Some things become idiomatic, others don't, there's no logic to it. It's like trying to explain why different fashions come and go.

Perhaps, but the latter 3 subquestions are answerable and could give some insight.

@Barmar There are a number of constraints on which nouns are eligible to become verbs; for instance, nouns ending in suffixes like -ness are almost never verbed. This question is likely answerable by someone smarter than me.

There are a few historical uses of nightmare as a verb (Oxford English Dictionary has several listed here: https://www.oed.com/dictionary/nightmare_v).
In terms of why it didn't catch on, your guess is as a good as mine - but I would support what a few commenters have said about dream being shorter, more convenient, and crucially more common than nightmare. Common words change much more and faster than less common words (see also - https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/37503/what-is-the-reason-for-having-irregular-verbs).
